# @Disabled is not working in JUnit5

Tags: java, eclipse, junit5

I want to use Junit 5 in Maven project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I want currently to disable the test:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Disabled;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

@Disabled
public class DatabaseFeaturesBitStringTest {
    .... 
}
```

But it's not working. Tests are executed after mvn clean build. Can you advise what I'm missing?

Comment: Can you tell if the result says no tests were skipped? It should be working as desired but maybe it looks like the disabled test was executed. When I run a test class containing one disabled of **n** test cases, the result looks like **Runs: n/n (1 skipped)**

Comment: Tested with maven 3.5.3 and junit-jupiter-engine 5.0.1, works fine, test is skipped.

Comment: @staszko032 can you please paste your POM configuration? Probably I'm missing something.

Comment: Before that, could you check if you configure maven-surefire-plugin in POM?

Comment: Yes - I was missing maven-surefire-plugin in POM. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

This is caused by incompatibilities betweeen `maven-surefire-plugin` and `junit5`. Your either have to define a version with at least `2.22.0` for the `maven-surefire-plugin` (see [codefx blog - junit 5 setup](https://blog.codefx.org/libraries/junit-5-setup/)) or just use maven `3.6.0`.
Additionally you have to have the dependency to the jupiter-engine defined as already stated in the very first lines of this question above:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
   <version>5.4.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you defined a dependency to the artifact `junit-jupiter-api` only, which is sufficient to get the test compiled and run with junit5, the `@Disabled` annotation will be silently ignored and the particular test will get run as well.

Comment: Was having this issue and I had to update my surefire plugin as mentioned but 3.0.0-M1 still didn't work but 3.0.0-M2 did.

Comment: 2022 This doesn't work anymore. `Dependency 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.0' not found`

Comment: I have org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.9.3:test and surefire-junit-platform-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2 but still running into this problem.

Comment: @user1034912 : version `5.4.0` of `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine` does definitely exist, must be soemthing wrong with your repo configs: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine/5.9.0

Comment: @morpheus explicit dependency to `surefire-junit-platform` is not needed. You only need to ensure the use at least version `2.22.0` of `maven-surefire-plugin` or version `3.6.0` of maven.
Official docs:  https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html

Comment: thanks. What is weird is that I am working on a multi-module project Disabled does work on a project but does not on another. The one on which it does not work is a Spring project and class has SpringBootTest annotation on it. anyone run into this?

Answer (score 6):

Check your configuration of surefire plugin for junit-jupiter-engine dependency. I am not sure, but I believe it should be configured in order to load all features from engine artifact, including Disabled annotation.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit.platform.surefire.provider.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Are you sure for the dependencies? Without them it's running also.

Comment: I took it from https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build, without such dependencies my JUnit 5 based tests are not called by maven, maybe it is version dependent.

Comment: surefire provider is not needed anymore, https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1536

Comment: @rmuller is right. The Surefire and Failsafe warns about using an external JUnit5 provider. These plugins already have their own providers. Please see this tutorial http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html

Answer (score 1):

@staszko032
The xml code in POM you described is the era of 2018. In 2019 we adopted JUnit5 provider to Apache project and the code https://stackoverflow.com/a/52056043/2758738 is no more legal.

@Jens Vagts
There are no incompatibilities between JUnit5 and Surefire/Failsafe because Apache plugin uses JUnit5 platform launcher which does all this trick.Surefire and Failsafe plugin does not execute your tests. So there is nothing to be incompatible, since all the work is done by JUnit5 engines and not plugin's code. It is the real engine defined in your POM which executes the tests. The plugin only triggers the engine which does all the work and sends the events back to plugin.

Please see Apache documentation:

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check if Jupiter conditions (`@Disabled` in your case) are deactivated via configuration parameter `junit.jupiter.conditions.deactivate`.

Please see JUnit5 documentation for more details: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-conditions-deactivation

Answer (score 0):

this might be problem with improper imports. i solved it by removing all junit import statements and re-imported all junit classes properly.